# xrandr: Configure crtc failed

Tags: linux, xrandr, antergos

I'm trying to make my Linux machine work with a 4k monitor. There's no 4k option in listed resolutions, so I tried to add it myself and here's what I got:

```
$ cvt -r 3840 2160 60   
# 3840x2160 59.97 Hz (CVT 8.29M9-R) hsync: 133.25 kHz; pclk: 533.00 MHz        
Modeline "3840x2160R" 533.00 3840 3888 3920 4000 2160 2163 2168 2222 +hsync -vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160R" 533.00 3840 3888 3920 4000 2160 2163 2168 2222 +hsync -vsync  
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI1 3840x2160R  
$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 3840x2160R
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I'm using Antergos with Deepin DE, Intel HD 620 Graphics and LG 4k monitor. I have tried to connect this monitor to PS4 and other laptops with Windows and it seems to work fine. Live CD with Manjaro KDE gives me the same error message. Trying to specify crtc gives no effect, all of them fail. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out. The problem wasn't actually in Linux or xrandr, but my integrated graphics card just isn't capable of 4k output at 30fps, it worked at 15fps though so if you got the same problem, try smaller framerates.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that was caused by the default resolution recommended by `arandr`. Reducing the secondary display's resolution fixed the issue.